# How to group and use colour in Python networkX using CSV datasource?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, networkx

I am importing CSV data into networkX but cannot get the grouping or the colours to work.  When i include them I get a Key error of 'group'. My CSVs are set up with the headers: 
Nodes: 'name', 'group', 'nodesize' 
Edges: 'source','target','value'

When i remove all code related to groups or colours it produces a Graph.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

G = nx.Graph(day="Stackoverflow")
df_nodes = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/classic.123456/Documents/Nodes.csv')
df_edges = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/classic.123456/Documents/Edges.csv')

for index, row in df_nodes.iterrows():
    G.add_node(row['name'], group = row['group'], nodesize=row['nodesize'])

for index, row in df_edges.iterrows():
    G.add_weighted_edges_from([(row['source'], row['target'], row['value'])])

color_map = {1:'#f09494', 2:'#eebcbc', 3:'#72bbd0', 4:'#91f0a1', 5:'#629fff', 6:'#bcc2f2'} 

plt.figure(figsize=(25,25))
options = {
    'edge_color': '#FFDEA2',
    'width': 1,
    'with_labels': True,
    'font_weight': 'regular',
}
colors = [color_map[G.node[node]['group']] for node in G]
sizes = [G.node[node]['nodesize']*10 for node in G]

"""
Using the spring layout : 
- k controls the distance between the nodes and varies between 0 and 1
- iterations is the number of times simulated annealing is run
default k=0.1 and iterations=50
"""
nx.draw(G, pos=nx.spring_layout(G), **options)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.collections[0].set_edgecolor("#555555") 
plt.show()
```

Comment: which line is throwing the error?

Comment: colors = [color_map[G.node[node]['group']] for node in G]